# Delete row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, delete-row

I want to delete rows in my table where `Date` is not equal to `GetDate()` but my query is not working it says that there is no row affected.

Here is my SQL query:

```
DELETE Message 
WHERE DateSent != (SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
```

Here is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT 
   Account.Username + ' ' + '(' + convert(varchar, Message.DateSent, 101) + ')' + ':', 
   Message.Message, Message.samplecolumn 
FROM 
   Account 
INNER JOIN 
   Message ON Account.EmpID = Message.EmpID 
ORDER BY 
   Message.MessageID
```

Comment: What's the type of `DateSent`?

Comment: datetime, because i am using sql server 2005.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what rows should be affected? `select top 10 * from message`

Comment: Values of what precision do you store in DateSent?  2012-01-01, 2012-01-01 22:30 or...?

Comment: @BrianWillis see my update.

@Tahbaza 2013-02-19 00:00:00.000 is the format in my sql server because i convert the date to `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 0):

if `DateSent` is date, you don't need to convert `GETDATE()` value into string.

```
Delete Message where CONVERT(DATETIME, DateSent, 101) <> GETDATE()
```

Comment: unfortunately the datatype of DateSent is datetime because i am only using sql server 2005.

Comment: i tried your solution but it also deletes the row where `DateSent` equal to `GETDATE`

Comment: @shio how about: `CONVERT(DATETIME, DateSent, 101) <> CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 101)`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, DateSent, 101)  <> CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)
```

This will delete all records with other dates, without considering time part.

Comment: thanks i'll try it. by the way, the value of `DateSent` is `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();`. do you think that has something to do with the issue?

Comment: still the query still deletes all the dates.

Comment: Does this query select any rows? : `SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DateSent, 101), CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)  
FROM tablename
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, DateSent, 101) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)`